# boost mutable_queue not compiling

Tags: c++, boost, queue, mutable

I have managed to work through (what appears to be) most of the initial problems, but due to the fact that some of my answers came from other people's (unanswered) questions, I am not sure if I am heading in the right direction. I am working with boost's [mutable queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/boost/pending/mutable_queue.hpp) and am having some issues when compiling.

My code, as it stands, is:

```
typedef struct _MyComparator 
{
    bool operator() (const PriorityStruct* arg1, const PriorityStruct* arg2) const
    {
        return arg1->key < arg2->key; 
    }
} MyComparator;

class PriorityQueue
{
    typedef PriorityStruct* entry;
    typedef boost::typed_identity_property_map<entry> prop_map; 
    typedef boost::mutable_queue<entry, std::vector<entry>, MyComparator, prop_map> priority_queue_notAmb;
    priority_queue_notAmb* pq;
    boost::mutex mut;
public:
    PriorityQueue(void);
}

PriorityQueue::PriorityQueue()
{
    pq = new priority_queue_notAmb(sizeof(entry)*2, MyComparator(), prop_map());
    PriorityStruct* ps = new PriorityStruct;
    pq->push(ps);
}
```

When I remove the final line, pq->push(ps), the code will compile and run when creating a new PriorityQueue type. As it is, I get errors that keep it from compiling.

And my errors are:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: PriorityQueue, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  PriorityQueue.cpp
1>C:\boost\boost\pending\mutable_queue.hpp(94): error C2679: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'PriorityQueue::entry ' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\vector(1119): could be 'const unsigned __int64 &std::vector<_Ty>::operator [](unsigned __int64) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=size_t
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\vector(1135): or       'unsigned __int64 &std::vector<_Ty>::operator [](unsigned __int64)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=size_t
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::vector<_Ty>, PriorityQueue::entry )'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=size_t
1>          ]
1>          C:\boost\boost\pending\mutable_queue.hpp(91) : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::mutable_queue<IndexedType,RandomAccessContainer,Comp,ID>::push(const IndexedType &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              IndexedType=PriorityQueue::entry,
1>              RandomAccessContainer=std::vector<PriorityQueue::entry>,
1>              Comp=MyComparator,
1>              ID=PriorityQueue::prop_map
1>          ]
1>          PriorityQueue.cpp(7) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::mutable_queue<IndexedType,RandomAccessContainer,Comp,ID>::push(const IndexedType &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              IndexedType=PriorityQueue::entry,
1>              RandomAccessContainer=std::vector<PriorityQueue::entry>,
1>              Comp=MyComparator,
1>              ID=PriorityQueue::prop_map
1>          ]
1>          PriorityQueue.cpp(5) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::mutable_queue<IndexedType,RandomAccessContainer,Comp,ID>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              IndexedType=PriorityQueue::entry,
1>              RandomAccessContainer=std::vector<PriorityQueue::entry>,
1>              Comp=MyComparator,
1>              ID=PriorityQueue::prop_map
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have been unable to find much information on this in regards to how it is used.

Edit: As an additional test, I added

```
cout << (pq->empty() ? "YES" : "NO") << endl;
```

to see if anything strange happened. It prints "YES" every time. I replaced pq->push with this, but will keep this as an updated note unless I receive a comment or two asking me to do otherwise for readability.

Comment: which boost library are you using? The `boost/pending/mutable_queue.hpp` appears to be quite dated based on my mailing list searches.

Comment: I am currently using 1.53. I noticed that as well, and because I was unable to find any solution on my own, I ended up creating my own based on std::list.

Comment: you might try the [priority queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/heap/reference.html#header.boost.heap.priority_queue_hpp) from the heap library, it appears to be better (or at least recently) maintained.

Comment: I was using it before I looked at mutable, but the main factor that makes it harder is the fact that I can't update it, which is the reason I switched to mutable in the first place. Although, after a recent development, a full pop and re-construction of the priority queue may be one of the best options.